# Get text of a neighbouring Textview on click

Tags: android, textview

I'm creating 4 textviews, storing strings in them. One of them has a string for a link, and it is hidden. These are being added to a ListView by a ListAdaptor. At runtime, it looks like this.

[image: Activity]

I need to be able to use the text within the hidden Textview when I click a neighbouring Textview. I've set an onClick adaptor for the Textview to be clicked. How can I get the text in the hidden neighbouring Textview? I tried using tags, but the concept is eluding me.

My layout resources: `list_item.xml` (trimmed):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"        
android:onClick="onClick"
android:tag="name"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/hash"       
android:visibility="gone"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/size"        
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/link"
android:tag="link"       
android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

Activity layout: `activity_main.xml`. [Full Code](https://pastebin.com/FtUAh7vN)

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Part of my [Activity code](https://pastebin.com/FtUAh7vN):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String Msg = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
//        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.getTag();
//        String Me = (String) v.getTag();

//      TextView txtlink = (TextView)v.getTag("link");
        String Me = txtlink.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICKED" + Msg + Me,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

When I click on the TextView with id title, I need to get the text of TextView with id link.

This is how I'm creating the ListView:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    MainActivity.this, showList,
    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"title", "url", "hash",
    "size"}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.link,R.id.hash, R.id.size});

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Full Code:
[MainActivity](https://pastebin.com/FtUAh7vN)

Comment: Where you using txtlink? In which XML you have txtlink

Comment: @Rahul In list_item.xml.

Comment: Ok, where you are initialising it

Comment: @Rahul I added links to entire code.

Comment: Why don't you add onItemClickListener on ListView

Comment: Can you give me a small snippet of code to show how to add the link url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150653/discussion-between-rahul-and-droidzone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `OnItemSelectedListener` and remove your onClick method from code and xml file.

```
lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, showList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```